# No puedo agregar una referencia en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un problema al agregar la ultima referencia de SisVentas a la CapaPresentacion(Es una biblioteca de clases de Windows Universal), me sale este mensaje:

[image: Las demás referencias se pudieron hacer con normalidad, pero en esta aparece un error.]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: necesitamos mas información. Que tipo de proyecto es la librería de clases, que versión de framework? Que tipo de librería? Está ya compilada. el proyecto  del proyecto donde la vas a agregar que tipo de proyecto es,  que framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ve a ajustes de la capa de negocio y datos, y cambia la opción de tipo de salida: a biblioteca de datos. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]